# Use render in Command Symphony 2.8

Tags: php, command, smarty, render, symfony-2.8

A cron is required to send email in symfony 2.8 .
The mail template is to be fetched in the command like we use render in controller. But in commannd there is no render function. Please suggest any method.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use `$this->get('templating')->render()`